# How to get bigger window in Embarcadero console apps

Tags: c, console-application

I'm using Embarcadero C compiler (under Windows 7) to create console apps.

An earlier version I was using allowed me to set the size of the window under Windows, and it would happily address whatever size I set (using gotoxy etc). In the latest version (which I use because it's 64-bit capable), it seems to be fixed at 50*80 (from memory) which is way smaller than I need.

**Question 1:** How do I set the maximum size of the console window in the Embarcadero C library?

One of the other reasons I'm using Embarcadero, rather than say Microsoft's Visual Studio (VC), is that I like to run the compiler from the command line without firing up the IDE.

**Question 2:** Can I use Visual Studio (VC) in that command line mode instead?

- I know I can set the console size easily in VC

I need to be able to use a console window of at least say about 180 columns, 120 rows.

Comment: Just a note: The MS VC compiler (and the other tools) can be run from the command line as well (although I don't know how). For this, there is a special entry in the start menu which opens `cmd.exe` using a batch file which sets the appropriate environment variables before.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to compile (but not start) the application in the IDE (Embarcardero or VS) and then start the compiled/linked executable from a separate `cmd.exe`? I sometimes do this with VS2013 to start/test applications compiled in debug mode. They run significantly faster in this case and I still can "attach" them to debugger at any time if necessary.

Comment: I'll look at getting MS VC running on a command line. I've looked for doco on that but it's cunningly hidden like a lot of MS stuff. I don't want to change to using an IDE because I have a nice lean, quick method of generating programs by just having a header file in a subfolder, I tailor the header file and compile and run it with a single batch command in less than a second. And I have several thousand folders with these tailored header files in them plus associated data files. To do this in an IDE would slow me down almost to a stop.

Comment: I don't know Embarcadero C compiler. Does it use the standard Windows console or its own console window? If it's the standard console then you should be able to use the same code as Visual Studio.

Comment: It's just a standard Windows console. And the code for addressing the cursor is the same... but the latest (64-bit) versions have an internal row/column limit that wasn't there in earlier versions. And I can find no way of changing those limits. If you address the cursor to (75,100) it just ignores you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I gave up on Embarcadero addressing more than 80 columns in console windows. Too hard/impossible. I switched to Microsoft which allows addressing whatever number of columns your console window has defined. Thanks @Scheff for pointing out it's fairly easy to run 'CL' from the command line once you start your console window from the model-specific shortcut they provide.

Add a day of mucking around getting the 'gotoxy' and 'clrscr' routines (and the interrupt handling routines) translated etc and I'm up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

- Run something to get the console to appear
- Right click the Console title bar
- Click Defaults
- In the Window Size box set the desired width and height
- Click Ok
- Gets kept as new default console size.

Comment: All true…but doesn’t answer the question which was about addressing rows/columns from Embarcadero C.